# Unable to generate a Power BI report of Intune data

Tags: powerbi, intune

I am unable to generate a Power BI report of list of computers deployed in Intune with their list of Applications installed on them.

I tried and checked in Intune reporting as well as in Power BI, but can't find how to create that report.

Any help please

Comment: Did the data import? "I tried" doesn't convey any useful information about where it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to look for a report that could provide this info in Intune and power BI but couldn't find one.

Comment: Are you using Intune PowerBI? 
Did you see this article? https://samuelmcneill.com/2022/07/11/how-to-custom-powerbi-reporting-from-intune-data/

Comment: Yes I installed it, linked it to datawarehouse, and went through all tables imported but couldn't find that information anywhere. I checked this article but it didn't provide a hint to what I am looking for, I ve already checked that with no result.

Comment: can you write a stored procedure in InTune to return the columns you want? But I guess if you have no idea what tables the data is in, you're outta luck.